# A complicated mysql join

Tags: php, mysql, join

Ok, I have this first table which has, among other things:

**table 1:** `id | depID` (every id has one depID)

Then, I have a second table where I have **table 2**: `userID | depID` (where an userID is associated with multiple depIDs in separate rows. Also, I have **table 3** with `userID | rankID` (where an userID is associated with one rankID).

I need to get all id and depID from table 1, and then to check, which userIDs of table 2 shares the same depID (table1.depID = table2.depID), and then, to check which of those userIDs from table 2 has rankID = $rID

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this SQL should get you what you want, but I'm not 100% clear from the wording of the question:

```
SELECT table2.userID
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.depID = table2.depID
JOIN table3
ON table2.userID = table3.userID
AND table3.rankID = $rID;
```